# Writing a list of xml nodes recursively in scala

Tags: xml, scala, recursion, nodes

I'm learning scala and have problem with writing an xml file.

Suppose I have a

```
case class Coordinate(x: Int, y: Int)
```

and

```
val l = List(Coordinate(1,3), Coordinate(2,4), Coordinate(3,5))
```

I need to print an xml file with the format:

```
<root>
  <object>
    <coord x="1" y="3"/>
    <coord x="2" y="4"/>
    <coord x="3" y="5"/>
  </object>
</root>`
```

I'm trying to implement it recursively so it will work on large amount of Coordinates data and multiple

```
<object>.
```

I have tried to print the output first to check the result with this:

```
def convertToXML(l: List[Coordinate]): Unit = {
  def eachCoordToXML(coord: Coordinate): scala.xml.Node = {
    <coord x={ coord.x.toString }  y={ coord.y.toString } />
  }

  val newObject =
    <object>
      { l.foreach(eachCoordToXML(_)) }
    </object>

  println(newObject.mkString)
}
```

and the result showed up something like this

```
<object>

</object>
```

Can anyone guide me here, what did I go wrong?
or is there any better/more efficient way to write xml node recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing everything right! You just need to use `map` instead of `foreach`!

`foreach` in scala returns `Unit`.